# How to modified url link in joomla 1.7

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am using joomla 1.7 .
I have added sub menu using joomla.
 But  when i click sub menu link its redirect to Url "www.xyz.com/2012-07-07/xyz". i want to remove date in this Url.
Plz Help me .
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to supply details of the menu item you added.  What kind of menu item it is, as well as what it's *supposed* to do.

Comment: first go to category or article file in joomla and write to alias name  each category or article file name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another menu item of type "Menu Item Alias". In the alias field put "xyz". There is parameter on right side "Menu Item", here you need to select the menu item 2012-07-07/xyz.

Do not show the newly created menu. And whenever you will click on 2012-07-07/xyz it will show you the alias xyz of newly created menu.

Comment: its depend upon theme facility or version if no type any alias name pls go to alias name of actual name of file.